# Terminal - autocomplete partial filenames

Tags: terminal, autocomplete

Let's say I have a folder with those files in it:

```
2017-10-16-first_lesson.pdf
2017-10-17-lesson_about_something.pdf
2017-10-23-about_something_else.pdf
2017-10-24-bash_autocomplete1.pdf
2017-10-30-bash_autocomplete2.pdf
```

Typing the full name is pretty inconvenient, and the standard autocomplete does not help.

- I'd like to type something like:  `evince first<tab>`
- and I'd like it to autocomplete to: `evince 2017-10-16-first_lesson.pdf`

I tried something like `evince *first*` and it's working, but looks pretty like a walk-around. And does not solve the problem of the last 2 lines:

- `evince *bash*` will open 2 files, and if you are using another program that accepts only 1 param it will open the first only or give an error.
- I managed to solve with something like `evince *complete1*`, but it sounds even worst.

How can I achieve this behavior?